# How do you safely measure large AC currents using a multimeter without a current clamp?

Tags: ac, current-measurement, safety, multimeter, high-current

I would like to measure the RMS current draw of several house appliances, in addition to the primary and secondary side current of a step-down transformer.

Simply placing my multimeter in series with the load through its leads will cause sparking due to the small cross-sectional area of my multimeter's lead tips (only speculating what would happen, I haven't actually tried it nor should anyone else). In addition, I would rather not have to repeatedly place my hands close to exposed live wires and sparks.

I have contemplated other alternatives, such as directly placing both sides of the wire I wish to measure the current through into the multimeter sockets after removing its leads. This is not an optimal solution since higher-gauge wires, such as 16 AWG (1.5 mm<sup>2</sup>), might slip or spark. Alligator wires rated for high currents and power shunts (though the latter may be less accurate if it were not designed for AC current measurements due to the skin effect) are an attractive option for this, however, I would like to know if there are other options available to me and what the usual procedure is for doing this kind of thing?

Note: The multimeter I have can measure RMS currents of up to 10 A (true RMS); I do not understand why it did not come with specialized alligator leads.

Comment: If you want to know "instantaneous" power consumption, you are better off with a *power meter* for some loads (ancient washing machines&tumbler, non-PFC "electronic" loads (sub-20 W CFL or LED "bulbs", decades old consumer electronics)). For long term measurements, there are "electricity" meters - some have a significantly higher power consumption than a traditional induction motor one.

Comment: _"I do not understand why it did not come with specialized alligator leads."_ Cost.

Comment: _"series with the load through its leads will cause sparking due to the small cross-sectional area of my multimeter's lead tips"_ Are you hot inserting your multimeter in series? Don't! Power down and install it properly. Better yet, get yourself a clamp current meter. Safer for everyone involved.

Comment: @winny my whole question was about finding out a "proper" method to do so, and I never said I would install it while the plug was connected, but even so, connecting a multimeter in series through leads is still dangerous.

Comment: So how did you get a spark?

Comment: _”though the latter may be less accurate if it were not designed for AC current measurements due to the skin effect”_ At 50/60 Hz, this is nothing you need to worry about.

Comment: @winny I was speaking hypothetically: if I place a multimeter in series through its leads, I would assume there will be sparking due to the small cross-sectional area of the tip and also partially due to some unavoidable hand movement (connection-disconnection).

Comment: _”hand movement”_ = hot insertion. Ok, you need to stop what you are doing, take three steps back and call an electrician before someone gets electrocuted or a house burns down. [RM: If hand movement can affect results then the procedure is more dangerous than is necessary].

Comment: @A.H.Z I'm a moderator. Winny's comments might have been worded slightly more "kindly" **BUT** they are aimed at keeping you alive and your house intact. Interupting substantial currents at mains voltages can cause some very dangerous situations, and an accidental short with a movable hand held probe can in some instances lead to an arc which is potentially fatal. ||  See next comment.

Comment: At a minimum until you are very experienced with such things (and even then, ideally) measurements should be made using equipment which is connected or disconnected with power off and with connections made by means certain to handle the load current. Some form of "clips" may be suitable but typical crocodile clips and leads typically aren't. || You mention placing the power leads in the meter sockets. DON'T. A good alternative is to connect the power leads and meter probe ends via suitably rated screw down connector blocks.

Comment: @winny Your advice is good. I'm sure your wording sounds getle enough to you (and I'd not have found it notable) BUT it's surprisingly easy to misjudge how such wording comes across to some.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Sure thing, I’ll keep it in mind. My point is that mains electricity does not care about best intent or anything like that, it will zap anyone for any mistake.

Comment: Just buy a pair of generic alligator-clip leads to use with your multimeter. 99% of multimeter test leads are similar enough that generic ones with "banana-plugs" on the ends will work fine.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I understand, though as I said above, I DID NOT plug my multimeter leads anywhere near mains voltage, and in fact was pointing out the reasons why I shouldn't. Like I said I was speaking hypothetically to better explain where I'm coming from and what I should do to improve my setup in regards of safety.

Comment: @A.H.Z  It woul;d be useful if you made it clear in your question what you did NOT do or intend to do. You mentions sparks, which only occur when a circuit is made or opened with power on.

Comment: @winny Thanks. I have no doubt about your good intentions and, as I noted, your advice was good. || Mains electricity is so non-selective that it has even occasionally zapped me, dspite my best intentions t avoid this. I'd managed to avoid this for a decade or maybe two when I got caught out in July 2017 -  a fuse on a switchboard had a missing insulation "blob" over a live screw. I grasped the earthed housing with one hand and contacted the live connection with the other -  shocking!!! I'll try not to do anything like it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You suggest the possibility of placing the power leads in the meter sockets.

- DON'T!

There are too many possibilities for unintended consequences.

If you have two wire ends, as you mention, a good alternative would be to connect the power leads and meter probe ends via suitably rated screw down connector blocks. Using probes in this manner is a "non standard" application - done sensibly with due attention to shock hazards it could be done in an electrically safe manner.

I may update this image with an improved one but for now, this shows how connection could be made.
The probe is the "wire" on one side and the mains lead is the wire on the other.  The simple screw type connectors would be adeqyate if properly sized.
Power must be disonnected while connections are made or broken.

[image]

Images from [here](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2F1.bp.blogspot.com%2F-hp0NuhNDXgM%2FWqF50pddDbI%2FAAAAAAAADFo%2FsKlR9SNTCfwxWNMOIE2Z4dyjl0FrMr1-ACLcBGAs%2Fs1600%2FScrew_terminal_block_with_crimped_wire.jpg&tbnid=TzYeV22ToCKd0M&vet=12ahUKEwjPtNbCjYX-AhV0DLcAHYO2D6MQMygJegUIARCXAw..i&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.electricaleasy.com%2F2018%2F03%2Fterminal-block-types.html&docid=3OxORnGz_dgfwM&w=500&h=329&q=connector%20block&ved=2ahUKEwjPtNbCjYX-AhV0DLcAHYO2D6MQMygJegUIARCXAw)
Ledt hand image is copied by them from Wikimedia.

Answer (score 4):

Most people would buy a plug in power monitor for ordinary household appliances.  Electricians might use a test lead, with the three cores separated, and a clamp meter.

If you're going to do this regularly, you could make up an adaptor, using the plug and socket from an extension lead, and insulated 4mm plugs to fit the multimeter.  That way, you could set up the multimeter connections, then simply plug the appliance in.

The leads supplied with multimeters are mostly for probing around electrical or electronic appliances.  The probe handles are designed to keep your hands away from the bare metal while you are holding them.